# Is there a way to create a date input field that can allow for 00 for DD / MM inputs if values are unknown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've been trying to create a date picker field that can allow for certain invalid date ranges i.e. 00 if the DD or MM for a date of birth is of an unknown value. The base UI components that I am using are MUI's DatePicker and MUI's FilledInput / TextField. For instance, a person with a birth date of March 1943 should be able to input their DOB as 00 / 03 / 1943 on the front end.

So far, as far as I understand and read, this can't be done with input fields of 'type = "date"' as 00 would be autocorrected to 01.

As a continuation to the above question, I have used a standard text field instead with masking, such as react-imask library and it works (sort of haphazardly). A key feature that I am still missing if I were to use a text field is that my text input is not split neatly into each date block (Day,Month,or Year) like the MUI example attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32bcN.png)

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to build such a custom date picker using date inputs?
2. If not, would using a text field be a suitable solution to the problem?
3. How can I get the described behavior to get my blocks of text to correspond to each date block?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular text field and add a regex pattern to enforce a certain format.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const DateInput = () => {
const [date, setDate] = useState('');

const handleDateChange = (e) => {
    const inputDate = e.target.value;
    const formattedDate = inputDate.replace(
    /^(\d{0,2})\/(\d{0,2})\/(\d{0,4})$/,
    (match, p1, p2, p3) => {
        const day = p1.padStart(2, '0');
        const month = p2.padStart(2, '0');
        const year = p3.padEnd(4, '0');
        return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
    }
    );

    setDate(formattedDate);
};

const handleBlur = () => {
    // Validate date
    // ...
};

return (
    <input
    type="date"
    pattern="\d{0,2}/\d{0,2}/\d{0,4}"
    inputMode="numeric"
    placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
    value={date}
    onChange={handleDateChange}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    />
);
};

export default DateInput;
```

Comment: Thanks!! It does help, but is there a way to make the different date blocks distinct blocks? For example, I should be able to click onto the 'DD' block and only edit dates, or the 'MM' blocks to edit MM directly.

As it is, I have to fill in the dates in order, so if I want to edit my 'YYYY' values, I have to fill in values for 'DD' and 'MM' first before getting to 'YYYY'

Answer (score 0):

For maximum re-use, I suggest you offer *two* input fields, one for birthdays with date and one without:

```
<TextField label="Birthday" type="date"/>
<TextField label="Month of birth" type="month"/>
```

This MUI code looks different, but works like the HTML code below:

```html
<div>
Birthday <input type="date"/><br>
Month of birth <input type="month"/>
</div>
```